# Cannot read properties file with web app (Maven web app with JSF)

Tags: jsf, web-applications, properties-file

I have a properties file: hibernate.properties inside default package. I am trying to read it from a class inside another package: com.somepackage.SomeClass.

In a normal desktop application, the following input stream is working:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/hibernate.properties");
```

But with my web app (A maven web application created using Netbeans with JSF 2.2 as dependency)

I tried these alternatives:

Using class:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/hibernate.properties");
```

Using external context:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/hibernate.properties");
```

Using context class loader:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/hibernate.properties");
```

Each of these return null. How do I read the properties file inside the default package?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking on the wrong location for the file. `hibernate.properties` is usually not saved in the root of the deployment. Open your .war file and look up the location of `hibernate.properties`. If you have your application deployed to `localhost:8080/app1` you need to call `/app1/` to access the contents of your deployment.

Comment: Ok. oddly when I created hibernate.cfg.xml from Netbeans wizard, it showed up inside: "Other sources (src/main/resources)". I had assumed it would be insde: <default package>. Let me put all the resources into src/main/resources

Comment: Just open your .war with for example winrar and take a look where it really is.

Comment: I myself created hibernate.properties file.

Comment: My Point is that you need to look how your .war is created. Just the location in the .war matters